# Delay NSDocument Close

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to schedule a task or wait until the task completes execution while a `NSDocument` closes. I have overridden `-canCloseDocumentWithDelegate` method and want to wait here until the task completes. The task is spawned from a background thread but switches execution to the main thread.

I tried the following

```
-canCloseDocumentWithDelegate
{
   if( condition )
   {
      // Run the task and wait for the task to be completed.
      scheduleTask;
      dispatch_async_on_main_queue( canCloseDocumentWithDelegate )
      return;
   }
   if( taskRunning )
   {
      // Wait until the Task completes.
      // Set a handler that'll be called on task completion.
      // Invoke canCloseDocumentWithDelegate from callback.
      callback = dispatch_async_on_main_queue( canCloseDocumentWithDelegate )
      setCompletionHandlerForTask( callback );
      return;
   }

// if the condition didn't match or the task completed continue Document Close
[super canCloseDocumentWithDelegate];
}
```

This works as long as the user wait. But if the user clicks the close again, the app crashes since the taskRunning case queues multiple callbacks.

I'm not sure if this the right way to do it. I wonder if there is any delegate or something that would do this.

Comment: The user clicks on the close button and nothing happens. Do you telll the user to wait? `canCloseDocument` is no longer supported. Use `canCloseDocumentWithDelegate:shouldCloseSelector:contextInfo:`.

Comment: I'm using canCloseDocumentWithDelegate:shouldCloseSelector:contextInfo: only. I can display a progress bar to indicate to the user that close document is waiting on the task.